# Read environment variables from logback configuration file

Tags: java, logging, environment-variables, logback

I have this logback.xml file:

```
<configuration debug="true" scan="true" scanPeriod="60 seconds">

  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
      <Pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</Pattern>
    </layout>
  </appender>

  <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <File>${MY_HOME}/logs/mylog.log</File>

    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
      <FileNamePattern>logs/my.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</FileNamePattern>
      <MaxHistory>30</MaxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>

    <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
      <Pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level - %msg%n</Pattern>
    </layout>

  </appender> 

  <root level="TRACE">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
  </root>

</configuration>
```

And `${MY_HOME}` is a defined system variable (`echo $MY_HOME` on linux shows the correct path).

The thing is that logback doesnt seem to read it properly, it stores the logs under `MY_HOME_IS_UNDEFINED/logs/my.log`

What am I doing wrong? Thanks a lot!

EDIT: I made a mistake and put OSC_HOME where I really meant MY_HOME. Sorry about that

Answer (score 85):

Contrary to what the others have said, the [logback documentation explicitly states](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#variableSubstitution) that "During substitution, properties are looked up in the local scope first, in the context scope second, in the system properties scope third, and ***in the OS environment fourth and last***".  So if the property is defined in the environment, logback will find it.

I was having the same issue when running my project in Eclipse.  If that's the issue you're having, it can be fixed by going to Run Configurations -> Environment and adding `MY_HOME` to the environment variables.

Not really sure why it isn't loading the native environment by default.  There's even an option called "Append environment to native environment" which doesn't seem to have any effect for me.

Comment: Environment variables are working for me, but I had to restart Eclipse to get them picked up. See my answer to this question

Comment: This is the same for IntelliJ IDEA. A full restart of the application will pick up the environment variables.

Answer (score 34):

There is an alternative way to read environment variables from config file. you can put your custom variables to logback context with context listener.

**logback.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration debug="true" scan="true" scanPeriod="30 seconds">

    <!-- THIS IS OUR CUSTOM CONTEXT LISTENER -->
    <contextListener class="com.myapp.logging.listener.LoggerStartupListener"/>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>[%-5level] %d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%.6thread] %logger - %msg%n</pattern>
            <charset>UTF-8</charset>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="FILEOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${MY_HOME}/${LOG_FILE}.log</file>
        <append>true</append>
        <!-- Support multiple-JVM writing to the same log file -->
        <prudent>true</prudent>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- Daily rollover -->
            <fileNamePattern>${MY_HOME}/${LOG_FILE}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
            <!-- Keep 7 days' worth of history -->
            <maxHistory>7</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>[%-5level] %d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%.6thread] %logger - %msg%n</pattern>
            <charset>UTF-8</charset>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
        <appender-ref ref="FILEOUT"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

**LoggerStartupListener.java**

```java
package com.myapp.logging.listener;

import ch.qos.logback.classic.Level;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.LoggerContextListener;
import ch.qos.logback.core.Context;
import ch.qos.logback.core.spi.ContextAwareBase;
import ch.qos.logback.core.spi.LifeCycle;

public class LoggerStartupListener extends ContextAwareBase implements LoggerContextListener, LifeCycle {

    private static final String DEFAULT_LOG_FILE = "MYAPP";

    private boolean started = false;

    @Override
    public void start() {
        if (started) return;

        String userHome = System.getProperty("user.home"); 

        String logFile = System.getProperty("log.file"); // log.file is our custom jvm parameter to change log file name dynamicly if needed

        logFile = (logFile != null && logFile.length() > 0) ? logFile : DEFAULT_LOG_FILE;

        Context context = getContext();

        context.putProperty("MY_HOME", userHome);
        context.putProperty("LOG_FILE", logFile);

        started = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isStarted() {
        return started;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isResetResistant() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(LoggerContext context) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onReset(LoggerContext context) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop(LoggerContext context) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onLevelChange(Logger logger, Level level) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Needed logs to include the aws ec2 instance id. This was the approach I had to take.

Answer (score 21):

You perhaps mean `MY_HOME`. In your config file there is reference for `OSC_HOME`. See [Variable substitution](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#variableSubstitution) rules of Logback for details.

You can pass environment variable as a Java System property and then Logback will perform the variable substitution. You can pass this as JVM option in your command line. For example:

```
java -DMY_HOME=${MY_HOME} -cp ... MainClass
```

Or You can define MY_HOME in your config file itself.

```
<configuration debug="true" scan="true" scanPeriod="60 seconds">
  <property name="MY_HOME" value="/home/my" />
  <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <File>${MY_HOME}/logs/mylog.log</File>
  </appender> 
</configuration>
```

Comment: From the link in your answer: "During substitution, properties are looked up in the local scope first, in the context scope second, in the system properties scope third, and ***in the OS environment fourth and last***."  So it should be looking at os environment variables right?

Comment: @TimPote Yes, it will look at OS environment variables

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Eclipse you have to restart it to pick up environment variables, but you **can't** use: File -> Restart

Instead you actually **have to fully shut it down and then start it back up** again.

Answer (score -5):

Things are actually working as designed: logback doesn't read environment variables at all when doing variable substitution. Quoting the [documentation](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#variableSubstitution):

> The value of the substituted variable can be defined in the configuration file itself, in an external properties file or as a system property.

So, either use one of the mentioned solutions or get `OSC_HOME_IS_UNDEFINED` :)

Comment: Logback does read OS environment variables. Under [Scopes](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#scopes) it mentions 'OS environment' which is a link to Oracle's documentation on environment variables

Comment: The above quote indeed implies that OS environment variables are not supported. However, I could not find the above quote in the documentation. The current docs explicitly mention OS environment variables.

Answer (score -6):

Instead of using environmental variables, you can use  tag to declare variables in logback.xml.