# Prevent instantiate of specific appender

Tags: java, logging, log4j, logback

[I choose a log appender dynamically by using a Java system property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975939/read-environment-variables-from-logback-configuration-file#answer-1976031) like this

```
<configuration>
  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
      <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </layout>
  </appender>

  <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <prudent>true</prudent>
    <append>true</append>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
      <fileNamePattern>${logLocation}/%d{yyyyMMdd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>          
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender> 

  <root level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="${logAppender:-STDOUT}" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```

As you can see the default value of the `logAppender` variable is `STDOUT`.

Problem is that even when the `STDOUT` appender is selected, the `FILE` appender is instantiated and keep making `logLocation_IS_UNDEFINED/%d{yyyyMMdd}.%i.log` file on the root of the project.

Can I prevent instantiate of `FILE` appender not to make the useless directory and file?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can remove the FILE appender as you don't need it.

```
 <fileNamePattern>${logLocation}/%d{yyyyMMdd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
```

Seems like you have not initialize the variable logLocation that is why you are getting file name with "logLocation_IS_UNDEFINED". Declare your file location and use like below. you will get right file name at right location .

```
  <fileNamePattern>${logLocation}/${FILE_NAME}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
```