# how to define logback variables/properties before logback auto-load logback.xml?

Tags: java, logback

My company has an environment management tool that enables you to look up properties from the environment programmatically in Java. I want to leverage this tool to configure logback. For example, suppose I have a logback.xml as follows (the file appender section in particular):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <!-- console appender -->
    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd/HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{20}: %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <!-- file appender -->
    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>${LOG_FILE:-/default/log/file/path</file>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd/HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{20}: %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

So, in this case, I want to look up the `LOG_FILE` property from the environment (or OS, if you will), and pass it to logback before logback loads the logback.xml so that it will know the value of `LOG_FILE`. So, how can I achieve that? BTW, I know how to define a file appender programmatically, but that's not what I want here.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Using the standard Logback Groovy support might be the easiest approach.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After quite a bit of scratching my head, I am settling with the following solution.

First, put logback.xml outside classpath so that logback will not automatically load anything.

Second, add the settings from the environment to system properties so that logback can look them up when parsing logback.xml.

Third, programmatically configure logback in the application code. (The official logback documentation has [one nice example](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#joranDirectly) of that. )

Done.

Comment: Hi JBT. Thank you. I did something slightly different. I kept the logback xml file inside the classpath but I named it as "out-logback.xml". Once it is a name which the logback does not scan, I was able to kept the config file inside the jar.

Answer (score 17):

[Define a property](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#variableSubstitution) in `logback.xml` and load it into the "context":

```
<property scope="context" name="logfolder" value="${location.of.the.log.folder}" />
```

Then define your appender referencing the property:

```
<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>${logfolder}/logfile.log</file>
    <append>true</append>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>[%d{ISO8601}] [%p] [%t] [%c] [%m]%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

From the [documentation](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#scopes):

> A property with context scope is inserted into the context and lasts
>   as long as the context or until it is cleared. Once defined, a
>   property in context scope is part of the context. As such, it is
>   available in all logging events, including those sent to remote hosts
>   via serialization.

So the default scope, which is "local" may well be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks, Alexandre. However, this doesn't solve my problem. I want `${location.of.the.log.folder}` as in your example to be defined before logback loads any configuration.

Comment: I found this worked by specifying -Dlocation.of.the.log.folder=dir on startup

Comment: You can also import all properties from your `*.properties` file - eg. `<property resource="application.properties" />`

Answer (score 11):

> I want to look up the `LOG_FILE` property from the environment (or OS, if you will)

#### Here are the alternatives:

1. If by *environment*, you mean what's generally known as [environment variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable), you can [refer to them directly in the configuration file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10109584/1036728) without much hassle.
2. If you don't mean environment variables, but rather something that requires custom code to access, you can [implement a custom ch.qos.logback.core.spi.PropertyDefiner](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#definingPropsOnTheFly) that grabs and returns the value.

   e.g.

   ```
   public class MyCompanyEnvironmentGrabber extends PropertyDefinerBase {

       @Override
       public String getPropertyValue() {
           return ...; // grab the value from company environment
       }
   }
   ```
3. There's [apparently](https://www.mkyong.com/logging/logback-set-log-file-name-programmatically/) reports one can programmatically set up a variable before `logback.xml` is loaded by putting it before any calls to `logger`, and being careful of the ClassLoader load order...  However, I think this is very brittle as *not using `static logger`* is very hard to control when the code base becomes complex.

All told, since `logback.xml` is loaded almost immediately after the Java instance starts, safe ways of dynamically setting the value to a variable seems limited to:

1. Setting it outside the Java program, such as through a calling shell script, by the use of environment variables or system properties (`-D`).
2. Returning it via the `ch.qos.logback.core.spi.PropertyDefiner` callback.
3. Setting it up [in a `ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.LoggerContextListener` as done in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23969706/1036728).
4. Artificially delaying the loading of `logback.xml` [as how the OP has done in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24272855/1036728).

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

In logback.xml reference your Property by %property{myProperty}:

```
    <appender name="console" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
        <pattern>
            %property{myProperty} - %m%n%wEx
        </pattern>
    </encoder>
    </appender>
```

Set the Property during the application runtime:

```
LoggerContext loggerContext = (LoggerContext)LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
loggerContext.putProperty("myProperty", "myProperty12345");
```