# Is it possible to add logback.xml configuration values from DB?

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot, logback, syslog

I want to configure logback.xml values dynamically from database.
This is my logback.xml file:

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="KIWI" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SyslogAppender">
        <syslogHost>localhost:8080</syslogHost>
        <facility>LOCAL0</facility>
        <suffixPattern>%thread: %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</suffixPattern>
    </appender>
    
    <logger name="com.javacodegeeks.examples.logbacksyslogexample.message.kiwi" level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="KIWI" />
    </logger>
</configuration>
```

I want get the syslog host name information from database, instead hard coding here directly. Is that possible?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: why would you do that? Can you give a bit more explanation

Comment: I don't want direct dependency between syslogconfiguration like hostname and my java service. If I can get the values from database, i don;t have any dependency between my java service and syslog service configuration. If I want to change the syslog configuration i can change in the database and that will be reflected here.

Comment: I'm not sure if putting a logging configuration in the database is the way to do it. For syslogHost you can set that through parameter and then pass it from the code to the logger. Look here, maybe it will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24235296/how-to-define-logback-variables-properties-before-logback-auto-load-logback-xml/24235375.  https://openwritings.net/pg/java/pass-variableparameter-logbackxml

Comment: "For syslogHost you can set that through parameter and then pass it from the code to the logger." Can you please explain how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in the comment I don't think that storing the logging configuration in the database is a good idea. If I understood correctly, your concern is how to change appender configuration depending on some variable. This can be solved by using an MDC filter or simply reading the values from your service properties.

If you want to read some values from your application.yml or env vars you can simply use spring expression.

However, if you want more flexibility and control you can use the MDC filter where you can set whatever you want and pass it to the logback configuration.

http://logback.qos.ch/apidocs/ch/qos/logback/classic/turbo/MDCFilter.html

In the following link you can see how to do the mapping and basic usage of the MDC for logback:
https://www.baeldung.com/mdc-in-log4j-2-logback

Here is my example of how I used the MDC filter. Basically, depending on which organization is logged in when a request comes I parsed it and set it in MDC from where then it can be read by logback when writing the logs.

Java config:

```
@Component
@Order
public class MDCFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig fc) throws ServletException {
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest sr, ServletResponse sr1, FilterChain fc) throws IOException, ServletException {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        String username = "System admin";
        String organization = "System-Club";
        if (authentication != null) {
            if (authentication.getPrincipal() instanceof UserDetails) {
                UserDetails springSecurityUser = (UserDetails) authentication.getPrincipal();
                username = springSecurityUser.getUsername();
                String apd = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
                orgnization = apd.getOrganization().getName();
            } 
        }
        if(orgnization != null) {
            MDC.put("orgnization", orgnization.replaceAll("\\s+","_").toLowerCase());
        }
        try {
            fc.doFilter(sr, sr1);
        } finally {
            if (username != null) {
                MDC.remove("username");
            }
            if (orgnization != null) {
                MDC.remove("orgnization");
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }

}
```

logback.xml:

```
 <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.sift.SiftingAppender">
        <discriminator>
            <key>organization</key>
            <defaultValue>System</defaultValue>
        </discriminator>
        <sift>
            <!-- A standard RollingFileAppender, the log file is based on 'logFileName' at runtime  -->
            <appender name="FILE-${organization}"
                      class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
                <file>/home/demo/logs/${organization}/org.log</file>
                <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
                    <pattern>%-5level %date{dd.MM.yyyy. HH:mm:ss} - Organization: %mdc{organization} - %logger{35} [%L]  - %msg%n</pattern>
                </encoder>
                <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
                    <fileNamePattern>/home/demo/logs/${organization}/org.%d{dd.MM.yyyy}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
                    <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
                    <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                        <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
                    </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
                </rollingPolicy>
            </appender>
        </sift>
    </appender>
```